# How to Call an IP with a Specific Host Using HttpClient

Tags: .net, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient

How can I make a call to an IP while specifying host information using .NET HttpClient object? We are using subdomains to differentiate between hosts but we also need to provide a specific IP for accessing our test environment servers.

Example:
We would like to make a call to https://12.34.56.78 but we need to make sure that the call accesses a specific subdomain (i.e. https://specific_subdomain.company.com)

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to provide a Host header that specifies the host information:

```
public async Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(string subdomain, string endPoint)
{
    var siteUrl = $"https://{subdomain}.company.com/";
    var siteUri = new Uri(siteUrl);
    var client = new HttpClient {
        BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://{12.34.56.78}:443"),
        Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
    };

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", siteUri.Host);

    // Make the request.
    var result = await client.GetAsync($"/{endPoint}")
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    var responseString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(responseString);
}
```

If you also need to attach some cookie (i.e. an auth cookie) to the preceding code you can do so like this:

```
public async Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(string subdomain, string endPoint, Cookie cookie)
{
    var siteUrl = $"https://{subdomain}.company.com/";
    var siteUri = new Uri(siteUrl);
    var client = new HttpClient {
        BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://{12.34.56.78}:443"),
        Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
    };

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", siteUri.Host);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", $"{cookie.Name}={cookie.Value}");

    // Make the request.
    var result = await client.GetAsync($"/{endPoint}")
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    var responseString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(responseString);
}
```